# Cannot loop through files using Azure Data Factory wildcards correctly

Tags: parameters, wildcard, azure-data-factory

In my source folder (Azure Blob Storage) I have, among others, two csv files named:
retails.csv
retailsitems.csv

My copy activity is set to get the file name as `pCollection*.csv`, as I use some json conf files where pCollection is defined for those files as 'retails' and 'retailsitems' respectively.

It looks alright and works for all other files smoothly. However, for these two specifically it gets only the 'retailsitems.csv' file.

Why?

And how can I fix that without messing the other files?

Comment: If I don't misunderstand your question,you want to copy `retails.csv` and `retailsitems.csv`,so why don't you set the wildcard paths like `retails*.csv`?

Comment: Because there are more files than retails and retailsitems, such as items, customers, accounts, etc.

Anyway, I just solved my own problem. I put the wild card inside the json parameter file. It worked without interfering on one another.

Comment: Congratulations that you figured it out! I help you post it as answer. You can accept it. This can be beneficial to other community members. You also could post yourself when you come back and I will delete mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"put the wild card inside the json parameter file. It worked without interfering on one another."

I help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.